# Using Whitelist of Mac address for Sftp login in Centos 7

Tags: firewalld

i would like to configure firewalld in my server. Its possible to use iptables by whitelist the mac adresss.I want to do Sftp login by Mac address. So far ive search the internet but got no solution. I am very new to this, hope someone can help me.Thank you for answering this question.

Comment: you cant implement that kind of rule when connections are coming from the internet.

Comment: and a MAC addresses can be spoofed rather easily... It would be safer to use regular SSH authentication with a key on each machine (provided that you can avoid the key being passed around (password on key or other)).

Comment: to me using mac address is safer as they wont be changed (like ip address) if it was logged into another computer.which means if they want to open it, they must use the same computer where its being set up ie. office.

Comment: actually... no. As stated by @xenoid MAC ADDRESS's are extremely easy to spoof.

Comment: Just google "spoof mac address"...

Answer (score 0):

If the connections are coming from the same network you can use the solution provided by @Izzy [in this post](https://serverfault.com/a/519483/444868)

Comment: but that post using iptables..